# How to give pyinstaller execution privledges for PyQt modules in virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am writing a GUI application in the Python 3.11.3 language using PyQt6.  In addition, I am writing this on Arch Linux.  The software runs correctly, and I am now trying to transform the code base to an executable using `pyinstaller`.  I am using version 5.12.0 of `pyinstaller`.

I run the `pyinstaller` while I am in a virtual environment using the command `pyinstaller -F -w -i icon.ico --add-data "todo_six:todo_six" todo.py`, and the process runs to completion; however, the executable produced by the process does not work, and I get the following warnings during the process, indicating that `pyinstaller` needs executable permission to many PyQt libraries.

```
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/home/jonwebb/apps/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/QtSql.abi3.so'
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/home/jonwebb/apps/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/QtDBus.abi3.so'
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/home/jonwebb/apps/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/QtWidgets.abi3.so'
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/home/jonwebb/apps/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/QtGui.abi3.so'
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/home/jonwebb/apps/todo_six/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/QtCore.abi3.so'
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1'
```

I can fix this by writing a script to execute the `pyinstaller` library with `chmod +x` statements for each package, but I do not think you should need to if `pyinstaller` works correctly.